# Como pasar un proyecto de angular a uno nuevo sin errores

Tags: angular

buenas, tengo un error que no logro solucionar en un proyecto de Angular, al instalar Sweetalert 2, de repente me dejo de funcionar, y probando otras soluciones al error, me ha dado otros diferentes, por lo que he pensado en crear un nuevo proyecto, y pasar todo lo que tenia al nuevo, para asi solucionar los errores.

Como puedo hacer esto ??? Ya que lo que se me ha ocurrido es crear uno nuevo, y copiar la carpeta SRC al nuevo proyecto, pero me sale un sin fin de errores.

Un saludo.

Comment: Cuál es el error?

Comment: Ya lo he logrado pasar a uno nuevo, a veces es mejor empezar de cero XD

Answer (score 1):

Ya lo he logrado, siento las molestias, pero estaba muy agobiado.

Si hace falta que algún moderador elimine esta pregunta, ya que no tiene utilidad para la comunidad.